# Как вывести данные в Input value="" Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Подскажите как нужно правильно вывести INPUT в форме со значением которое передает контроллер при рендеринге которое берет из модели. Делаю вот так но почемуто значение пусто
 `<?= $form->field($model, 'ship_fname')->textInput(['value' => Html::encode($model->ship_fname)]) ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы все правильно делаете за исключением

```
['value' => Html::encode($model->ship_fname)]
```

Yii2 достаточно умен чтоб сам подставлять туда значения, по этому вам нужно просто написать

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ship_fname')->textInput() ?>
```

И все будет работать, это первое.

Это может не работать если вы создали модель на основе **BaseModel** как это показано в офф. документации. Чтоб все работало выборку данных нужно делать через **ActiveRecord** модели которая отвечает за объекты модели самой БД или передать данные ActiveRecord в вашу модель которая наследуется он **BaseModel**

Comment: Спасибо! А то не знал как сделать, посредством Yii